# How to calculate in PHP the difference in seconds between 2 times (not datetimes) just times. Laravel // PHP // Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, time, difference

Here is an example to make the issue clear. Both below examples are giving wrong difference:

```php
// gives 86398 while the correct is 2sec
$diff_in_sec = strtotime('23:59:59') - strtotime('00:00:01'); 

// again gives 86398 while the correct is 2sec.
$diff_in_sec = Carbon::parse('00:00:01')->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse('23:59:59'));
```

What I want is for `23:59:59` compared with `00:00:01` to return 2 seconds difference, and
`00:00:01` compared with `23:59:59`.

Comment: Just to clarify i completely understand why both above examples give the result they give. And indeed they are working fine, but this is not what i want. I want the pure absolute difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to convert these to datetime unfortunately. How is php to know that 23:59:59 and 00:00:01 do not occur on the same day?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is assign both to variables, and see if the second time is before the first. If so, add a day. Then check the difference:

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse('23:59:59');
$date2 = Carbon::parse('00:00:01');
if($date2->lt($date1)) {
   $date2->addDay();
}

$date2->diffInSeconds($date1); // 2
```